# Should I have the web version of an app in the same Flutter project for android and iOS, even though the web version is 100% different?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter

I have a Flutter app running on both android and iOS (Flutter + Firebase) but I'm implementing an admin dashboard that will only work on the web version. I was thinking about developing the dashboard with python + react but since it is a pretty simple interface, I've decided to develop it in Flutter web.

My question is: Should I have the admin dashboard be a separate Flutter project or should I keep it all on the same code base?

Answer (score 0):

It always depends, but since the admin interface seems to be completely independent from the rest and does not share code with the mobile application, I would make a second (Flutter) project out of it.

If your admin interface depends heavily on tables, maybe use something different than Flutter. The material tables which come with Flutter are rather limited at the moment.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking at the moment. If I were developing it in another language, this would be the case anyways. A couple of classes would be shared amongst admin (web) and app (ios/Android), along with some helper functions, but I don't think it is worth it. The project is already big by itself, adding all of the admin into it seems like a lot.

Comment: A third option would be to create a dart package to share common models and business logic between the two projects.

Comment: That's a great idea Tim! I'll take a look into it. Thank you so much for your response.

Answer (score 0):

On the Firebase side, it all depends on what data the apps needs to access.

If your iOS/Android and admin apps all need to access the same user list, database, or any other data in Firebase, they need to be in the same Firebase project.

If the apps access separate data sets, they should be in separate Firebase projects too.

---

On the Flutter side, for me, it depends on the number of icons, binaries or installations.

If any user (including yourself) can only have a single app installed, and it switches mode based on for example sign-in credentials, then I'd make it a single app.

If even a single user can have multiple of the apps installed, I'd make them separate apps.

Comment: Both iOS/Android and Admin Dashboard will be part of the same Firebase project since they access the same information and write to the same documents. The big difference is in how that information will be presented and the navigation (admin dashboard would have it's own routeGenerator for example), and that's why I was considering having a different Flutter project for it.

Comment: Ah, this was about the Flutter project. I. missed that. There I'd start with a separate project, since you're gonna send a different app to different people.

Comment: Yes! haha That's what I've decided to do btw. Thank you for your response Frank!